# Assistance in merging my code with some code I found on this site that may solve my problem

Tags: excel, vba, printing

I have a workbook that prints a single sheet on each loop inserting different data each loop. The issue we have is our network printer uses a print queue driver based at our head office we get an error as our connection is very slow.

I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42301046/14018349) on this site which may solve my issue

This may well allow us to just send 1 `job` with 35 `pages` instead of 35 single page jobs which it seems to not like.

I am just not sure how to merge this into my code or indeed if it will solve the issue.

This is my code:

```vb
Sub PrintFormsNBC()
    Dim StartRow As Integer
    Dim EndRow As Integer
    Dim msg As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    
    StartRow = Range("NBC!StartRow")
    EndRow = Range("NBC!EndRow")
    
    If StartRow > EndRow Then
        msg = "ERROR" & vbCrLf & "The starting row must be less than the ending row!"
        MsgBox msg, vbCritical, APPNAME
    End If
    
    For i = StartRow To EndRow
        Range("NBC!RowIndex") = i
        If Range("NBC!Preview") Then
            ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
        Else
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut
        End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("NBC").Activate
End Sub
```

I can see it also runs a loop just not sure which parts are needed to add to mine.

Comment: That is not VB.NET code. Please read the description of a tag before applying it to your question. The description of the VB.NET tag explicitly states that it is not to be used for VB6, VBA or VBScript questions. I assume that this is a VBA question but you haven't used that tag either. Please be more careful when tagging questions, for our sake and yours.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, it is a VBA question and that is the tag I used. I am sorry if I have done something incorrect, I have only posted a couple of questions before.

Comment: This question was originally tagged with VB.NET. Another user removed that and added VBA and Excel.

Comment: Oh sorry must have been a typo, was certainly meant to be vba cheers

Answer (score 0):

From the referenced code, I think you only might need the `Application.PrintCommunication` line for one of the following solutions

1. The Easiest way to solve your printer back-up issue would be to introduce an
   `application.wait no() + timevalue("00:00:05")`
   Or some such period of time into each loop. I would likely work but it comes with a long list of cons: Slow, not perfect reliability
2. Next you could check the ready status of your printer each loop, and wait until it shows a ready status ( `do until /printerready/ = true... loop` ) however I just spent the last half hour trying to make that work on my device, and failed. I'm sure it's very do able... just not a "Quick" solution.
   Pros: more reliable, likely faster (or at least just fast enough)
   Cons: time intensive to implement
3. You add an additional sheet, that's setup like 50 blank versions of the same report. Each loop, you just copy all the data you've pulled to the next "Report". Make sure your page breaks are setup correctly: `Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$C$5"` [link to MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pagesetup.printarea). Then print that page. Use `Application.PrintCommunication`
   Pros: As long as you're careful about avoiding `.copy` and `.paste` this will likely be the fastest method. It should be very reliable.
   Cons: you might be stuck with a very long sheet just setup for printing.

Honestly, I'm lazy and would likely just ask the printer to `app...wait...`

Comment: Thanks Cameron I have done the 1st option and also added some code to collate so it prints double side each print job, will fine tune the time to wait. Once again thansk